# Rename alias in jazzhub

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops

I want to change https://hub.jazz.net/project/user1 to https://hub.jazz.net/project/user2 ... i.e. just change the name from user1 to user2.
I have checked update profile section and it allows update to a lot of fields but not profile id (i.e. user1).
I am not looking at changing ownership since Bluemix id is same ... just renaming user1 to user2.

Answer (score 1):

Aliases are permanent and cannot be changed. However, you can create another alias and link to it from your DevOps Services account.

Create a new alias:

1. Log in to [DevOps](https://hub.jazz.net/) Services, click the Profile Settings icon, and
   click Profile.
2. On your profile page, click EDIT PROFILE.
3. Click PERSONAL INFORMATION and change your email address to another email address that is not associated with your IBM id. **Note**:To verify which email address is associated with your IBM id, click [here](https://www.ibm.com/account/profile/us?page=signinview).

Unlink your email address:

1. Log in to [DevOps](https://hub.jazz.net/) Services by using your IBM id.
2. Go to the [Unlink your Jazz ID](https://login.jazz.net/psso/proxy/unlink?redirect_uri=https://hub.jazz.net/) and IBM id page and click Unlink Accounts.
3. After your accounts are unlinked, log out of DevOps Services.

Associate your new alias with your IBM id:

1. Log in to [DevOps](https://hub.jazz.net/) Services by using your IBM id.
2. Enter your new alias, accept the DevOps Services terms of use, and click Finish.
3. On the Success page, click Continue. Then, click the Profile Settings icon and click Profile.
4. Verify that your new alias is listed with your name.

more details here: https://hub.jazz.net/docs/faq/#alias_change